# Any way to get text outside of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, clipboard, bots

I'm building a concept project of a voice controlled intelligent home system.

I've written a basic conversation system with JavaScript. This way I can use Google Voice Input field to recognize speech, and this works much better than any dedicated voice recognition software (especially because it is in Polish) or API.

Long story short, I need to copy the computer responses to the clipboard (my voice synthesiser scans the clipboard for changes and reads it aloud).

Is there ANY way to push a JavaScript variable to the system clipboard? 
Or, even better, any way to get a variable content "outside" of a local html/js file and intercept it with visual basic or something like that.

PS. I tried ZeroClipboard and zClip but they seem not to work locally and also require a user interaction.

PS2. This is an non-commercial, self-contained, non-cross-platform project, so it may be a ugly workaround.

**EDIT: For the record: Since what I was trying to achieve here is apparently virtually impossible, I decided to rewrite the project and use Android instead of JavaScript. Android has a wonderful support for both Google speech recognition and speech synthesis.**

Comment: Have you thought about sending it with ajax to the webserver hosting your HTML/JS? The server is probably able to do these tasks, and I guess you run it locally..?

Comment: This might be an ultra hackish solution...why not use virtual keypresses for CTRL  + C (copy) and CTRL + V (paste)

Comment: And what about the Clipboard API (http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/#x1-introduction)

Comment: Thanks! I'll investigate your ideas in a sec!

Comment: Okay so unfortunately, no luck so far. As to sending data to the server, running a server for the sole purpose of triggering a COPY command seems an overkill.. (but if everything else fails, I'll try this direction). Simulating a Ctrl+C will not work in Chrome ("for security reasons") and the Clipboard API doesn't allow this kind of behavior (copying without user interaction).

Comment: You can try AppJS. With that you can build a desktop app in HTML/CSS/JS and it supports copying to Clipboard. Don't know if it needs user interaction though.

Comment: Tim, AppJS is great! But I've just tested it and it doesn't support the Voice Input field. Bummer...

Comment: I also tried saving a file or writing to a environment variable but no effect... it seems that JavaScript is sandboxed to the point of not being able to communicate with the OS in ANY way at all.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange, I never used it, but I think you should be able to do that.. Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/appjs/appjs/wiki/Clipboard-Copy The first code block shows you have to disable the security..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using AppJS. Here's a guide explaining how to copy to the clipboard:

http://github.com/appjs/appjs/wiki/Clipboard-Copy

The first code block shows you how to disable security..

Comment: AppJS is great but it doesn't support Google Voice Input control. And that's a game stopper. It seems that voice input is only implemented in Chrome and it stops working when the html5 file is displayed on any other browser/platform. But since this is perhaps as close as it gets to what I'm trying to achieve, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I also came along TideSDK, it's mostly the same as AppJS. Found a page where they use the Speech Input: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK-WebKit/blob/master/LayoutTests/fast/speech/speech-bidi-rendering.html